# how to correctly accommodate the values?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like how to put the second result of the second query. the value is shows under row and I want that value is in front of the first result query.

The result should be shown where it is marked in red

[image]

```
$resultados=$reporte->facturaCompleto();
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
{
    $bandera=0;
    echo "<tr style=''>";
    echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fila["factura"]).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fila["rfc_emisor"]).'</td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    //
    $id_documento=$fila["id_documento"];
    $reporte->set('id_documento',$id_documento);
    $reporte->contador();
    $contador=$reporte->get('contador');

    $id_documento=$fila["id_documento"];
    $reporte2->set('id_documento',$id_documento);
    $resultadosmov = $reporte2->movimientos();
    while($fila2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadosmov))
    {

        echo'<tr>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fila2["no_parcialidad"]).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fila2["importe_total"]).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

}
echo '</table>';
echo "</td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: Have you considered not putting empty `<td>`s and closing the `</tr>` before your row is actually done?

Comment: yes, but the rows of the second query will be inside of the first part

Comment: You need to do a better job explaining what you want the result to be.  Can you show an example that has it the way you want, based on the original data?

Comment: I need the values that are in the last rows to be in front of the first ones, as you can see the result of a jump down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo all the columns when processing the second query.

```
$resultados=$reporte->facturaCompleto();
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
{
    $bandera=0;
    //
    $id_documento=$fila["id_documento"];
    $reporte->set('id_documento',$id_documento);
    $reporte->contador();
    $contador=$reporte->get('contador');

    $id_documento=$fila["id_documento"];
    $reporte2->set('id_documento',$id_documento);
    $resultadosmov = $reporte2->movimientos();
    if ($resultadosmov->num_rows > 0) {
        while($fila2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadosmov))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fila["factura"]).'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fila["rfc_emisor"]).'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fila2["no_parcialidad"]).'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fila2["importe_total"]).'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            // Make 1st two columns blank in additional rows
            $fila["factura"] = ""; 
            $file["rfc_emisor"] = "";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<tr style=''>";
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fila["factura"]).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fila["rfc_emisor"]).'</td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

BTW, what is the `$bandera` variable for? It's set but never used.

It would probably be even better if you could join the two queries, instead of doing queries in a loop.

Comment: thanks but the values will be repeated and I need them to be shown but blank (in the first two columns) let's say they are subcategories of a category. and if "$bandera" does not matter

Comment: o: o :) or thank you very much, I really appreciate you